# echarts - Show label only when the heatmap cell is zoomed

Tags: reactjs, heatmap, echarts, echarts-for-react

I am currently on working echarts, and specifically with heatmap. I have a scenario. If I zoom into a cell, I want to display its label otherwise it is hidden. Can anybody help here.
Please find the Stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bvl4yu

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my question:

```js
// Declare "showLabel"
const [showLabel, setShowLabel] = useState(false)
// Update "showLabel" when zoom
const handleDataZoom = (params) => {
  const { startValue, endValue } = params.batch[0]
  const showLabels = endValue - startValue < 1
  setShowLabel(showLabels)
};

const option = {
  // ...
  series: [{
    // ... 
    label: {
      show: showLabel // here using "showLabel"
    }
  }]
};
```